# How to get translation other than active language React i18next

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I have an input component that the user should enter in text in different languages. Therefore I want the placeholder to be translated to different languages, when the user chooses which language he wants to write in.
I do not want to change the active language of the page.

Does anyone know, how I can get the translation from the resources manually?

I am not using any tools to get the text translations.

I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
const [t, i18n] = useTranslation();
let translatedPlaceholder = t('Placeholder', 'de') // For translation to german
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just pass the lng option for the t function:

```
t('Placeholder', { lng: 'de' }) // For translation to german
```

https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/essentials#overview-options

Answer (score 1):

After some fiddling around with the i18n object, I can get the translation manually from the i18n object. This might only work, if the i18n object is initialized like in my project, but I thought I might post this answer nontheless.

My i18n object is initialized like this:

```
i18n
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        // fallbackLng, debug, detection, ...
        resources: {
            en: {translation: {'key1': 'translated text', ...}},
            de: {translation: {'key1': 'übersetzer Text', ...}},
        }
    )
```

You can get any translation manually by doing:

```
const [t, 18n] = useTranslation();
i18n.options.resources['en'].translation['key1']
-> 'translated text'
i18n.options.resources['de'].translation['key1']
-> 'übersetzter Text'
```